# How to print response content on Mitmproxy using Python

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I tried running the code like this:

```
def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if("..." in flow.request.url):
        print(flow.response.content)
```

But i always get the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'`
I don't know how to correctly retrieve the response content. Someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `flow.response` in the `request` hook. The `request` hook is triggered before mitmproxy sends the request to the target server, so you clearly don't have a response yet. The easy fix here is to use `def response(...): ...`.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks! :)